# Regex matching in reverse everything after character x

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to create a regex to match this:

string: `this-string-ends-1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427`

should return: `1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427`

i.e. return everything after the 4th "-" character from the end.

I have tried this:

```
([^-]*$)
```

But it just matches from the first. Note the first 3 items (this-string-ends) could be any range of values

Comment: You don't need regex for this. `split` by `-`, remove first 3 items and `join` remaining with `-`.

Comment: also the first 3 items could change, could be 4,5,6, etc

Comment: Does it matter when you're going to remove those?

Comment: You need to clear up your requirements. My guess is you want everything after the 5th hyphen from the right, not the 4th, based on your example and  comments.

Comment: If any of the provided solution worked. Please, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `preg_match`([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zREEYy/1)):

```
$str = 'this-string-ends-1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427';
preg_match('/([^-]+(?:-[^-]+){4})$/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427' (length=36)
  1 => string '1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427' (length=36)
```

***Regexless Solution:*** Here is a solution using `implode`, `explode` and `strrev`:

```
$str = 'this-string-ends-1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427';
$str = strrev($str);
$arr = explode('-', $str, 6);
unset($arr[5]);
$imp = implode('-', $arr);
$matched = strrev($imp);

var_dump($matched);
```

Output:

```
string '1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427' (length=36)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `preg_replace` function:

```
$s = 'this-string-ends-1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427';
$result = preg_replace('/.*?([^-]+(?:-[^-]+){4})$/', '$1', $s);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427
```

---

***Bonus*** solution with `explode`, `implode` and `array_slice` functions:

```
$s = 'this-string-ends-1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427';
$chunks = explode('-', $s);
$result = (count($chunks) >= 5)? implode('-', array_slice($chunks, -5)) : "";

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string     = 'this-string-ends-1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427';
$string = preg_replace('/^.*?-((?:[^-]*-){4}[^-]*)$/', "$1", $string);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45ac2dd427
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$
```

The regex searches for a string which has a string of chars different from '-' (`[^-]*`), followed by `-`, followed by the same pattern 4 time, **then** the string ends (`$`)

Testing on: https://regex101.com/r/49fCit/2 ,the output is:

```
1c25e41b-f5b2-4484-b5b8-7d45lac2dd427
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*){4}$
```

It will take the last 4 hyphen with combination of letters or numbers (or not ) in between

[image]

Comment: ([0-9A-z]*\-[0-9A-z]*){4}$

Comment: Edited the answer also.please confirm it is working or not :)

Comment: How do you use it? where is the code? Does it give the right result?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: `A-z` isn't what you think. Take a look at the ascii table to see the characters included in this range. Also the hyphen isn't a special character outside a character class, you don't need to escape it.

Answer (score -1):

You want to extract a substring of five groups of hexadecimal characters separated by four hyphens at the end of the string. You can do it with `preg_match`:

```
if ( preg_match('~(?>[^-]+-?\b){5}$~', $str, $m) )
    echo $m[0];
```

You can also be more explicit using `[[:xdigit:]]` in place of `[^-]`.